# Perfomance difference with reference in kotlin

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, reflection

My question is, if there are any performance differences when I use references in kotlin versus the "normal" approach (without). Let's say, we want to submit a list to a `ListAdapter`, we can use two approaches.

### Approach one

```
shoppingCartViewModel.productList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
     it.let(shoppingCartAdapter::submitList)
}
```

### Approach two

```
shoppingCartViewModel.productList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
     shoppingCartAdapter.submitList(it)
}
```

What should be the preferred approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is a third possibility (I guess...):

```kotlin
shoppingCartViewModel.productList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, shoppingCartAdapter::submitList)
```

Regarding performance differences see for example this [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/277473/is-there-a-performance-benefit-to-using-the-method-reference-syntax-instead-of-l), but shortly speaking, the difference is negligible. You should rather focus on which version is more readable. I would definitely try to avoid the first approach, which seams to me pretty confusing.